# Записать title во все div с определённым классом

Tags: javascript, html

Стоит задача получить title страницы и записать всё в div'ы с определённым классом. Я написал вот такой код:

```
var pageTitle = document.title; // получаем title
document.querySelector('.this_page_title').innerHTML = pageTitle; // Записываем в нужный блок
```

Но он записывает только в 1 div, а остальные оставляет пустыми. Вариант с querySelectorAll не записывает вообще. Не могу понять, где ошибка?

Comment: Использовать document.querySelectorAll вместо document.querySelector и в общем случае предусмотреть вариант, если заголовок не заполнен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если код ниже НЕ сработает, то причины может быть две:

- Отсутствие заголовка (например, как в сниппетах на этом сайте);
- Вы пытаетесь получить *title* родительского окна из `iframe` с другим доменом.

Решение первой причины очевидно - добавить заголовок.

```js
document.title = '567';
// Получаем title
let pageTitle = document.title;
// Создаём массив на основе полученной коллекции элементов и перебираем его
[...document.querySelectorAll('.this_page_title')].forEach((el) => {
  // Записываем в нужный блок
  el.innerHTML = pageTitle;
});
```

```html
<div class="this_page_title">1</div>
<div class="this_page_title">2</div>
<div class="this_page_title">3</div>
```

Вторая причина, из соображений безопасности, либо вовсе нерешаема, либо сильно ограничена в применении.